# Does order of attributes matter in script tags?

Tags: javascript, attributes, cloudflare

I have a WordPress plugin that enqueues a Javascript file. This is the current format:

`<script src='http://www.mywebsite.com/myscript.js' data-cfasync='false'></script>`

The 'data-cfasync' attribute is to instruct CloudFlare Rocket Loader to ignore the script, per [their KB](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436--How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-my-script-s-in-Automatic-Mode-).

However, CloudFlare's URL format is like this:

`<script data-cfasync="false" src="/javascript.js"></script>`

Notice the data-cfasync attribute is before the src attribute. Does that make a difference? Does the order of attributes matter?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't

Comment: Generally the order of attributes does not matter, but then again, I have no idea what Cloudflare does

Comment: The easiest way to find out is to test it.

Comment: Thanks for flagging as duplicate, I did search for the topic but didn't think the HTML references were relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of attributes in HTML [elements doesn't matter](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags). You can write the attributes in any order you like `id` last `onclick` first - it does not matter.

Comment: Why was this downvoted, I wonder?

Comment: @Pointy Attribute order matters to someone I guess :) It was so I would hit 3.5k rep precisely.